# How to Jackson Deserialize XML into Record - ignore root element

Tags: java, xml, jackson

XML Input:

```xml
<Root_to_unwrap><User name="a"></User></Root_to_unwrap>
```

Java Record:

```java
package x.y.z;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

public record User(@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) String name) {
}
```

Tried the following with Jackson version 2.13.3, both doesn't work:

Try #1

```java
  @Test
  void testCase1() {
    try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml")) {
      XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
      ObjectReader reader = xmlMapper.reader().withFeatures(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
      User user = reader.readValue(is, User.class);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      fail(ioe); // failed with "Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set final java.lang.String field x.y.z.User.name to java.lang.String"
    }
  }
```

Try #2

```java
  @Test
  void testCase2() {
    try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml")) {
      XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
      ObjectReader reader = xmlMapper.reader().withRootName("Root_to_unwrap").withFeatures(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
      User user = reader.readValue(is, User.class);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      fail(ioe); // failed with "Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name ('User') does not match expected ('Root_to_unwrap') for type `x.y.z.User`"
    }
  }
```

Any idea how deserialize XML into Record? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The *Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set final java.lang.String...* exception message is related to the fact that Jackson library because of the absence of a `JsonCreator` annotated method in the `User` record firstly creates the `User` record and then tries to modify the final field called *name*, then the exception. This scenario can be avoided adding a `JsonCreator` annotated constructor to your `User` record :

```
public record User(@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) String name) {

    @JsonCreator
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

I tried your code with the Jackson version 2.12 with no luck (maybe the constructor in the `User` record solves your issue with jackson 2.13, but I haven't verified it), using one [incremental reading](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) as suggested in the official documentation solves your problem:

```
File xml = new File("msg.xml");
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xml));
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
sr.nextTag(); //points to Root_to_unwrap tag
sr.nextTag(); //points to User tag     
User user = xmlMapper.readValue(sr, User.class);
sr.close();
```